# Set translucent statusBar in iOS with react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar

I'm trying to NOThave a translucent (default) StatusBar on iOS with React-Native but seems like this option is only available on Android?

```
class THapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar translucent={false} backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" barStyle="default"/>
        <Tabs></Tabs>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you solved this problem in some other way but I have the same problem. And as far to deal with this problem I'm implementing platform independent marginTop or paddingTop.

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
// Status bar height on iOS is 20 dpi
const marginTop = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0;
```

Comment: Interesting solution, at the moment I've built only for iOS but that will help me in the future to adapt it to Android!